# Java Serialization Object

Tags: java, android, serialization

For my android studio project I need to serialize a User object. The idea is to save and load this object, so when the application is closes (gets destroyed) the objects and it's attributes are saved and stored in a file. My problem is that I'm getting an error with loading the object. It's says there is no such file or directory named 'save.bin', although I tried to create it. Here is my code:

```
    public class SaveAndLoadManager{
        public void save(Object object){
            Log.d("Save", "saving object");
            try{
                File userInfo = new File("save.bin");
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(userInfo);
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
                objectOutputStream.close();
                Log.d("Save", "object saved");
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.e("Save", e.getMessage());
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.e("Save", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        public Object load(){
            Log.d("Load", "loading object");
            Object object = null;
            try{
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("save.bin");
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
                object = objectInputStream.readObject();
                objectInputStream.close();
                Log.d("Load", "object loaded");
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.e("Load", e.getMessage());
            }catch(StreamCorruptedException e){
                Log.e("Load", e.getMessage());
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Load", e.getMessage());
            }
            return object;
        }
    }
```

How do I properly create a directory?

Comment: Note that Java serialization is generally a bad way to store data for any length of time, as it's hard to debug and prone to problems if you change your classes. Using something like JSON is usually preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `User` is implementing `Serialazible`

```
File userInfo = new File("save.bin");
```

you can think about the above line, like a file object, called **"save.bin"**,  stored in the root, (`/`) on the the filesystem. This location is not writable by your application. Your application has the permission two write locations, one stored under `/data/data/yourapp`, and the other stored on `/sdcard/Android/data/yourapp`. Both should be access through the public api. E.g. you can use the pair  [openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int))/[openFileInput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)) to retrieve the `FileOutputStream`/`FileInputStream`

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("save.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("save.bin");
```

As mentioned by @androidLerner in his comment, 
you can find more info [here](http://%20developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html),

Comment: This link will take you through how to do it properly: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html